# What's with the gas?

Tags: dead-island

Some zombies appear to emit a greenish cloud of gas. When I'm in this cloud my screen changes color to show that something is happening to me. What is the gas doing to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gas is poisonous. If you are too close to or attacked by a zombie with poisonous gas around it, the gas will damage you and cause your health to slowly drain, very much like the damage over time effect of fire-based attacks.

Comment: Speaking of fire, it is super effective against gassy zombies.

Comment: @kotekzot So what you're saying is I should start with Charmander?

Comment: @Robotnik LMFAO